# How do I get the directory tree structure from a Github repository link

Tags: github, github-api, directory-structure

Given a github repo link, I want to generate the directory tree structure and display it in a web application UI.

Other than scraping the link, is there any other method which I can use through Github API perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you can clone the repository to your local machine. You can use the tree command line tool.

Use your package installer to install tree.

Mac users
`brew install tree`

Ubuntu and the likes
`sudo apt-get install tree`

Windows
`choco install tree`

To use the tool

`tree [options] /path/to/directory`

If the directory is not passed the current working directory will be used.

`tree --gitignore /path/to/directory`

Is one of the options i use often. It filter by using .gitignore files.

To view the available options
`tree --help`